# How to print selected number of lines in repeated fashion from a long file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, solaris, ksh

I want to be able print line 1,2,3,4,7 by skipping Lines 5,6,8,9 and repeat the pattern till the end of file.

**Sample INPUT:**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13
Line 14
Line 15
Line 16
Line 17
Line 18
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 7
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13
Line 16
```

Using Solaris 10, KSH. Would love an nawk or sed solution

Comment: from the duplicate, the last answer would be fastest - `awk 'BEGIN{ a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4] a[7] }; NR % 9 in a'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a pattern that repeats every nine lines.  Try:

```
$ awk '{r=NR % 9} r>0 && (r<=4 || r==7)' input
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 7
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13
Line 16
```

#### How it works

First, we use `r=NR % 9` to set `r` to the line number modulo 9.  Next, we select which of those nine lines we want to keep: `r>0 && (r<=4 || r==7)`.